# Django: Returning a template with POST parameters

Tags: jquery, python, django, python-2.7, django-forms

I have a table with multiple rows, each of which has an 'edit' button. On clicking this button, the user should redirect to a form with his details already prefilled. Now, I have defined data attributes inside the 'edit' button's definition:

```
<a href='#' class="edit-user" data-email="abc@gmail.com">edit</a>
```

Using JQuery, I'm deriving the value of the 'email' data attribute and passing it in a POST request to `/add-edit-user`, which is also mapped to the page which has my form:

```
$( ".edit-user" ).click(function() 
    {   
        var url = base_url + '/add-edit-user/';
        var data = {
            'email': $(this).data('email'),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken,
        };
        // $.post(url, data);
        $.post(url, data).done(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }).fail(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
```

The `/add-edit-user` URL maps to the following view where I'm trying to define my form object and pass on as a context variable to my template file:

```
def add_edit_users(request):
    form = AddUpdateForm(request.POST or None)
    data = {'form': form}

    return render(request, 'add_edit_users.html', data)
```

Now, my assumption was that if the user clicks on the 'edit' button, I'd set the 'email' parameter in a data attribute and pass it on in my POST request to `/add-edit-user` URL, after which I'll render my form template with the form object as a context variable which will display the form with `email` field already prefilled.

However, on clicking of the `edit` link, the page is not redirected to the form page, but I do get the entire form page's HTML in my response. How can I redirect the flow to my form's template so that my input fields are prefilled from the POST variables?

Comment: ajax post will not redirect you. Have you tried creating a form with hidden email field? Then submit it through the edit button.

Comment: @AjmalNoushad can you elaborate more on that? not sure if I understood how the flow would be.

Comment: Ok, I've added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to achieve can be done by creating a form like this:

```
<form method='post' action='/add-edit-user/'>
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="email" name="email" value="abc@gmail.com" hidden> 
   <button class="edit-user" type="submit">Edit</button>
</form>
```

This form sends value of the email field in post data to the url : **/add-edit-user/**. Resulting in redirecting to the url with the email field prefilled.

Comment: How can I then prefill this email value in a form which is on the `/add-edit-user' page?

Comment: Have you tried submitting this form? I think it will get prefilled since you pass request.POST as argument to the form. Look at action attribute of form